# Tried to cancel a transfer, now counter is off

Tags: transfer

I submitted a transaction like the following:

```
./tezos-client transfer 0 from tz1... to KT1... --fee 0 --force-low-fee
Disclaimer:
  The  Tezos  network  is  a  new  blockchain technology.
  Users are  solely responsible  for any risks associated
  with usage of the Tezos network.  Users should do their
  own  research to determine  if Tezos is the appropriate
  platform for their needs and should apply judgement and
  care in their network interactions.

Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Estimated gas: 13025 units (will add 100 for safety)
Estimated storage: no bytes added
Enter password for encrypted key: 
Operation successfully injected in the node.
Operation hash is '$HASH'
Waiting for the operation to be included...
^C
^C
```

And I tried to cancel it with ^C because it was taking too long to be injected.

Now I try the following transfer and it fails:

```
 ./tezos-client transfer 0.1 from tz1... to KT1... --burn-cap 0.257
Disclaimer:
  The  Tezos  network  is  a  new  blockchain technology.
  Users are  solely responsible  for any risks associated
  with usage of the Tezos network.  Users should do their
  own  research to determine  if Tezos is the appropriate
  platform for their needs and should apply judgement and
  care in their network interactions.

Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Estimated gas: 33542 units (will add 100 for safety)
Estimated storage: no bytes added
Enter password for encrypted key: 
Unregistred error:
  { "kind": "generic",
    "error":
      "Error while applying operation $HASH:\nbranch refused (Error:\n                  
Counter 1633007 already used for contract tz1... (expected 1633009)\n)" }
    Fatal error:
      transfer simulation failed
```

So next I tried using "-C  1633009" since that is what was 'expected' but I get this error:

```
./tezos-client transfer 0.1 from tz1... to KT1... --burn-cap 0.257 -C 1633009
Disclaimer:
  The  Tezos  network  is  a  new  blockchain technology.
  Users are  solely responsible  for any risks associated
  with usage of the Tezos network.  Users should do their
  own  research to determine  if Tezos is the appropriate
  platform for their needs and should apply judgement and
  care in their network interactions.

Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Counter 1633009 not yet reached for contract tz1... (expected 1633007)
Fatal error:
  transfer simulation failed
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I faced very much the same stuck situation when I injected an operation with (accidentally) a fee of 1 micro-tz. Because of counter errors like above I could not inject any more transactions for the same source account until I restarted tezos-node.