# Operation not included due to 0 fees, now counter is stuck

Tags: transactions, operation, transfer, fees

I've submitted a transaction following cryptium post https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/dlyev8/accounts_in_babylon/

```
tezos-client -A mainnet.cryptium.ch transfer xxx from tz1a to tz1b --fee 0 --force-low-fee
Waiting for the operation to be included...
^C
```

But it was never included because of 0 fees.

So I did it again with default fees, and the counter was off

```
Error while applying operation oonFKJguvYswtWC7qTdtBa87K3Q9LZFjGzpnfswZiQxi5WEFjsv:
branch refused (Error: Counter 1658707 already used for contract tz1a (expected 1658708))
```

Okay, no problem...

```
$ tezos-client -A mainnet.cryptium.ch transfer xxx from tz1a to tz1b -C 1658708
Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Counter 1658708 not yet reached for contract tz1a (expected 1658707)
```

...? Fine, let try 1658707 then:

```
$ tezos-client -A mainnet.cryptium.ch transfer xxx from tz1a to tz1b -C 1658707
Node is bootstrapped, ready for injecting operations.
Estimated gas: 10207 units (will add 100 for safety)
Estimated storage: no bytes added
Enter password for encrypted key:
Error while applying operation oonFKJguvYswtWC7qTdtBa87K3Q9LZFjGzpnfswZiQxi5WEFjsv:
branch refused (Error: Counter 1658707 already used for contract tz1a (expected 1658708))
```

I'm a bit stuck there, anyone has an idea ?

Comment: similar to https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/tried-to-cancel-a-transfer-now-counter-is-off, but I can't restart cryptium's node... and not really willing to start a rolling node today if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently waiting long enough and retrying the operation works.

Comment: can you improve your answer to provide more information. For example, elaborate that the question you linked in your comment suggests that the answer to this question should include a restart or optionally a wait of how long?